# if reboot server, all celery-tasks with ETA dissapear

Tags: django, redis, celery

any ideas to "persist" those tasks to be restored after a machine reboot?

the system is:

broker: redis server 2.4.8

redis==2.4.11

django-celery==3.0.9

celery==3.0.9

Comment: This depends on the visibility_timeout setting, (which is 1 hour by default) after this time any unacked messages are redelivered to workers.  This is more of a backup solution though, it's better for you to make sure that the worker exits properly before restarting the machine, you can do so by using the `celery multi stop_verify` command instead of `stop`. The generic-init.d scripts was updated in master recently to do so by default, so maybe all you have to do is update the celeryd init script.

Comment: you mean pip install -U celery ?

Comment: no, init scripts are not installed with celery.  you have to do that yourself as the destination location vary depending on the platform and distro. If you don't use the generic-init.d scripts then you must find some other way to ensure the worker instances are fully shutdown before the machine reboots.

Comment: btw, daemonization is documented in the Tutorials -> Daemonizing part of the Celery documentation.